# Disable entire screen touch except one component in react native

Tags: react-native

I have tried adding a transparent Overlay screen which disables the entire screen, but I want my button to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set zIndex to your Overlay component and to your Button component,
for example:

```
 <>
  <OverlayComponent style={{ zIndex: 100 }} />
  <Button style={{ zIndex: 1000 }} />
 </>
```

Your button will render over the transparent overlay :)